# How an Android Client can receive a reponse from Node.js server?

Tags: android, node.js

I was wondering , how can an **Android** client can receive a response or request from Node.js server? I am quite clear about to send a request to Node.js server using **SocketIO** or default **HttpRequest** but i am not finding any documentation in the web to receive a request or response from **Node.js** server.

Please let me know , if you have any solution or suggestion.

Comment: I think this link may help out: http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/

Answer (score 0):

I had written an answer for a similar question about sending an XML over to a web service and waiting for a JSON response:

```
/* 
* Getting the XML ready for sending 
*/ 
String xml = getXml(); // YOUR XML STRING  
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add( new BasicNameValuePair("XML",xml) );
/* 
* Getting ready to send and receive from server 
*/ 
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("/your/service/url");
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFromEntity(nvps));
post.addHeader("Content-Type","application/xml");
post.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
/* 
* Sending the file and waiting for response 
*/ 
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(post);
/* 
* Getting the JSON from the response 
*/ 
if( response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 ){
    String json = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    // PROCESS RESPONSE HERE 
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Yes thanks but how can i do the same thing using sockets? I mean using SocketIO

Comment: Wait, what language are you coding in? JavaScript? My solution is in Java

Comment: Client Side : Android (JAVA) , Server Side :  Node.js (JavaScript)

Comment: Yes, so my solution is valid :) I posted client-side.